# enable disable dyanmic elemets using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using jquery to enable disable input elements . But i am uanable to do for similar elements having same class

html code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<table>
 <tr>               
     <td>
        <input type="text" value="1" class="price" disabled></input>     <input type="button" class="enable" value="Edit"/>
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" value="1" class="price" disabled></input>  <input type="button" class="enable" value="Edit"/>
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" value="1" class="price" disabled></input>  <input type="button" class="enable" value="Edit"/>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

jquery code :

```
$(function(){
$('.enable',this).click(function(){
  $('.price').prop('disabled',false);  
  $('.enable').prop('value','save');  
});
});
```

either it works for all boxes or it dosent work

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLp0e76z/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` correctly in the handler itself

```
$(function(){
$('.enable').click(function(){
  $(this).prev('.price').prop('disabled',false);  
  $(this).prop('value','save');  
});
});
```

Comment: one small doubt ..if  `prev()` returns the previous element , how come it enables the correct box ?

Comment: @amolsingh, in your case, isnt the previous element the correct box itself?

Comment: previous element as in it takes the elements from the <td> ?

Comment: @amolsingh, `prev()` will get the immediate preceding element or sibling